# Why do I need to put a low pass filter in front of an analog to digital converter (ADC?)

Tags: circuit-analysis, adc

Is the low pass filter in front of the ADC just to filter higher frequencies or does it serve another purpose?

I am talking about the ADS8320 ADC.

Comment: You mean [Anti-aliasing filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing_filter) ?

Comment: yes,it could be that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A low pass filter is needed for most analog to digital converters (ADCs.)   Without the filter, frequencies above half the sampling frequency of the ADC will "wrap around" into the sampled data.  This is called ["aliasing."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)

For example, assume you have an ADC sampling at 20000 samples per second.   If you sample a 9000 Hz sine wave and record the data, then sample a 11000 Hz sine wave and record the data, then both sets of data will "look the same" - they will seem to have the same frequency content.

This picture from the Wikipedia [aliasing page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) show how it works:

[image]

Both the red and the blue sine waves produce the same sampled result (the black points.)

This effect is usually unwanted.  You usually want to capture all of the signal up to half the sampling rate without aliases.

You get rid of aliased signals with a low pass filter.

The low pass filter also removes high frequency noise.

Some ADCs have built in filters, some don't.  Even those that do will usually require a moderate low pass filter to reduce signals above some specified multiple of the sampling rate.

---

Sometimes you can make use of aliasing.

Say you have an ADC with a sampling rate of 2MHz.  Normally you would be limited to sampling frequencies below 1MHz.

If you use a band pass filter to pass signals only from 1MHz to 1.5MHz, then you could capture signals between 1MHz and 1.5MHz with your 2MHz ADC.

The frequencies will be mirrored, but that can be accounted for in whatever analysis of the data you do - or mathematically mirrored again so that everything is "right side up."

That kind of thing requires an ADC without a built in filter and some knowledge of the internals of the ADC.  Besides the sampling rate, you have to be sure that the analog parts of the ADC will pass the signals that you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Yea it's what @AJN mentioned, and is an anti-aliasing filter. This is to filter out frequencies that are out of the sampling bandwidth. I also saw in the datasheet that they have an RC Filter on the vref. If you have a lot of noise on your lines, I would highly recommend doing that. I have had a lot of success correcting noisy lines by doing that and with a small RC filter going into the VCC pin. I've done this with op-amps, ADC's and DAC's it's been surprising how well it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the usual RC input filter has another purpose besides anti-aliasing: compensating for ADC charge injection.

A successive-approximation (SAR) ADC works by using a track/hold switch to sample the input voltage onto an internal array of sampling capacitors. In track mode, the capacitors are connected to the input signal, and in hold mode, the capacitors are connected only to internal signals. By switching parts of the capacitor array around, the ADC determines the corresponding digital code (I'm oversimplifying the actual process, the 68HC11 TRM gives a good explanation of how it really works.)

When a SAR ADC is tracking the input signal before the conversion command, there is an internal switch that connects its internal sampling capacitors to the external input signal. The start-convert command makes that switch open (hold mode), and the SAR shuffles the charge that was stored on the sampling capacitors. After the SAR has finished conversion and determined the input code value, then the SAR switches back to track mode. At that point, the internal sampling capacitor array is suddenly connected to the input signal -- but the voltage on the sampling capacitor is not at the same voltage as the input signal, so there is a brief disturbance to the input signal due to this "charge injection" phenomenon. The effect is more noticeable with high-impedance signal sources and high-resolution SAR ADCs. If the input signal doesn't return to its correct value before the track interval ends, there will be significant measurement error. (One way to cure charge injection effects is to add an input buffer, another way is to increase the duration of the track time interval.)

The simple RC network in front of the ADC does look like an anti-aliasing filter, and it does perform that function, so the RC time constant needs to be selected with that in mind. But also, the RC filter's shunt C value should be somewhat bigger than the SAR ADC's internal capacitance array, and the filter's series R value should be about the same as the internal switch R value. Sometimes there are typical values given in the datasheet, sometimes it's indirectly given as a "recommended applications circuit".

If the RC filter's C value is too small, the charge injection (when entering track mode) could disrupt the input signal.
If the RC filter's C value is too large, the bandwidth will be reduced and the input may be "sluggish".
If the ADC has multiple input channels, there can appear a sort of crosstalk effect when switching from one channel to the next channel, as a residue from the previous channel.

For other types of ADCs such as sigma-delta this charge injection effect can be negligible, because the input sampling capacitance is less and the sampling rate much faster due to oversampling.